# Encrypt login and password in cookie to keep user logged in

Tags: php

What is the best alternative to encrypting data to use it in a cookie so that i can decrypt it later to validate the user data?

Currently saved: Login - Password and IP in an array and then encrypt it with the function.

is that safe?

```
$user_log = array();
$user_log[] = ['ip' => $user_ip, 'login' => $user, 'pass' => $pass, 'valid_example_key' => '36asd6123u129asdh']; //valid_example_key update every 3 minutes

setcookie('user_log', encrypt(json_encode($user_log), 'red27156@xauxafrubraysusellhollws8xbygabandmyfriendsinthwlrd'), time() + (86400 * 90), '/', null, true, true);

function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key) {
    $cipher     = 'AES-256-CBC';
    $options    = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;
    $hash_algo  = 'sha256';
    $sha2len    = 32;
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($pure_string, $cipher, $encryption_key, $options, $iv);
    $hmac = hash_hmac($hash_algo, $ciphertext_raw, $encryption_key, true);
    return base64_encode($iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw);
}

function decrypt($encrypted_string, $encryption_key) {
    $encrypted_string = base64_decode($encrypted_string);
    $cipher     = 'AES-256-CBC';
    $options    = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;
    $hash_algo  = 'sha256';
    $sha2len    = 32;
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = substr($encrypted_string, 0, $ivlen);
    $hmac = substr($encrypted_string, $ivlen, $sha2len);
    $ciphertext_raw = substr($encrypted_string, $ivlen+$sha2len);
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $encryption_key, $options, $iv);
    $calcmac = hash_hmac($hash_algo, $ciphertext_raw, $encryption_key, true);
    if(function_exists('hash_equals')) {
        if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) return $original_plaintext;
    } else {
        if ($this->hash_equals_custom($hmac, $calcmac)) return $original_plaintext;
    }
}

function hash_equals_custom($knownString, $userString) {
    if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
        $kLen = mb_strlen($knownString, '8bit');
        $uLen = mb_strlen($userString, '8bit');
    } else {
        $kLen = strlen($knownString);
        $uLen = strlen($userString);
    }
    if ($kLen !== $uLen) {
        return false;
    }
    $result = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $kLen; $i++) {
        $result |= (ord($knownString[$i]) ^ ord($userString[$i]));
    }
    return 0 === $result;
}
```

valid_example_key checks whether the key is reported and the same that is in the database to try to prevent cookie theft

- If the user misses the password 3 times, the script returns a captcha
- The cookie updates every 3 minutes, and the old no work because the valid_example_key changes.
- The cookie only changes if the user is on the site.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to encrypt this data? It seems quite 'costly', normally one would use sessions.

Comment: @Jeroen sessions expire faster, the cookie seems more friendly to me.

Comment: Session time can be configured: ```ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);``` Also I think your login mechanism is prone to denial of service attacks.

Comment: @Jeroen If the user misses the password 3 times, the script returns a captcha to avoid denial attacks

Comment: Do not use password or IP... IPs change, and you should not be storing passwords in cookies. That was eliminated as bad form 20 years ago. I'm not sure there is a security question here. You appear to be looking for a design pattern for logging in users into an existing session.

Answer (score 2):

> is that safe?

No.

For example, you seem to be using a very short encryption key named 'key' in your current scheme.

Also, you are reusing the same key for integrity (hmac) as you used for encryption.

Also, the fact that you are encrypting passwords at all is probably a bad idea.

Comment: It's a example, The encryption key "key" is not the real key I use, I use a key about 60 characters long with letters, numbers and some random special characters

Comment: Still a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

So, first of all: this would have very bad user experience. Your sessions all immediately die every three minutes, regardless of whether the user signed in 179 seconds ago or 7 seconds ago. You could do a sort of "grace period" thing where there's one or more older keys no longer used to create cookies but still valid to verify them, but that's a lot of complexity to solve a problem that only exists because you're not doing this the usual way. Similarly, tying sessions to IP will cause them to die randomly whenever people do things like switch between cellular and WiFi, or one WiFi network and another, or switch cellular networks (roaming), or DHCP just gives them a new IP address because it's allowed to do that, or... you get the idea.

> is that safe?

Maybe, if you don't actually store any of the keys in the source code. It's a weird approach, though. Assuming you are validating the password each time, and that the password is hashed with a good password hashing algorithm before storing it in the DB, you're going to spend a *ton* of CPU time just running password hashing. Indeed, it's probably infeasible (for any significant number of users) to perform a safe level of password hashing on every request, which arguably means you have to use unsafely fast hashes, and that downgrades "maybe" to "no".

It's probably fine that the system automatically invalidates all sessions for that user when their password changes (it can be bad UX, but it's much better, security-wise, than not having any way to invalidate other sessions), but there's no way to invalidate them except by either forcing such a password change (bad UX) or by changing the key (which invalidates *everybody*'s sessions, and that's extremely bad UX). This is once again a case of re-inventing what's already been done better before.

There's also the thing where you're storing the password under reversible encryption (in the cookies). This is something to avoid whenever possible. It's relatively low risk here, as an attacker would need both the key and some other user's cookie (both are hard to get, and the only way to get both through the same attack would be total compromise of the server), but that would yield their password. Normally, except during initial login, the server doesn't see or have any way to obtain the password at all. Reversible encryption also leaks some info about the password length, which is undesirable.

---

Using random session tokens is almost certainly a better idea. You can get all the protections you want, such as tying them to IP addresses, by just making that a column in the sessions table (or you can include the IP with the random token and MAC it, but that buys you very little). You can have per-token expirations, actually tied to the lifetime of the cookie. You can revoke tokens by means other than completely changing credentials, and it's easy to do that at password change if you want to. You don't have any secret keys you have to protect. You can perform a very fast single-round hash of the user-supplied token to check against the stored value (some auth systems don't hash session tokens in the DB, but that's a mistake; you only need a single round of any secure hash function though, nothing expensive) on every request, rather than a very expensive password-hashing operation. You can use an actually good work factor for your password hashing algorithm because it's going to be only rarely needed. There's way less crypto to get wrong (yours looks fine, aside from the key being used for two different algorithms, but I'd need to spend quite a bit longer with the PHP docs to make sure it's fine; less is better when the question is "how much crypto should this design have?"). There are way fewer long-term credentials (passwords) flying around the system at any point, and the session tokens are fixed-length regardless of password length.

Comment: I'll give the benefit of the doubt and keep it here then